# Broadcastreceiver not working after boot

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have created an apps that will receive notifications from firebase thus hoping to start the app service after user boot their phone so that they do not need to manually start the apps again. However, the broadcast receiver seems to just not working.

AndroidManifest.XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="net.simplifiedcoding.firebasecloudmessaging">

    <!-- Adding Internet Permission -->

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!--
            Defining Services
        -->
        <service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service android:name=".NotificationService"/>


        <receiver android:name=".Broadcast" android:exported="true" android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Broadcast.java (BroadcastReceiver)

```
 public class Broadcast extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
                Intent service = new Intent(context, NotificationService.class);
                context.startService(service);
                Toast.makeText(context, "Broadcast started", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


        }
    }
```

MainActivity.java

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        }
    }
```

I have checked the followings

1. Permission RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED declared and not within  tag
2. receiver tag is being written correctly

Am I doing wrong or still missing something else? Do I have to call it at mainAcitivity which I doubt I should ? Any guidance are much appreciated.

Comment: Get rid of the `Toast` outside of the `onReceive()` method, and make sure you launch your app manually at least once after installation to bring it out of the _stopped_ state. You can also remove the `if`, since it's not really necessary, if that's all you're using that Receiver class for.

Comment: @MikeM. thanks for the help. the Toast outside of the onReceive() method was a typo at here only, it was supposed to be outside of if statement. I have updated the question according to your suggestion and still not working. The Toast message never appeared.

Comment: Make sure the `<receiver>`'s `name` is correct; as you have it now, the `Broadcast` class should be in the same package/folder as `MainActivity`. Also, check your logs to see if anything's failing during boot, if you're sure you've run the app once yourself after installing it.

Comment: still couldn't make it work. I have even tried writing a very simple apps as taught in this link http://www.jjoe64.com/2011/06/autostart-service-on-device-boot.html but still not working. I also installed and tried the apps on actual mobile phone.

Comment: Well, that tutorial is outdated. Since 3.1, you have to have an `Activity` that you launch at least once after installation, otherwise your boot Receiver will not be delivered the broadcast. Does your `MainActivity` work OK, at least? Other than that, it's hard to say. What you've posted is itself correct; i.e., everything seems to be spelled correctly, and in the right places in the manifest, etc. You might try cleaning/rebuilding your project, removing the `Service` stuff from the Receiver temporarily, double-checking the Receiver class's location, etc.

Comment: Yea I do have MainActivity and its working well (Its just a default MainActivity after all). Its updated above if needed. We do not need to call the broadcastreceiver in the mainactivity right? I have launched the apps once before I reboot my phone but still no luck. Guess I will just continue my trial & error. Thank you so much for your guidance!

Comment: Sure thing. Also, keep in mind that it may take up to a minute or two for your Receiver to actually get the broadcast. It's not going to happen immediately after the home screen appears. And you may want to use something more definite than a `Toast` for testing; e.g., log prints, or a `Notification` right from the Receiver, or even starting up your `Activity`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the solution and it was a very dumb reason.

I'm using Oppo's phone to test and Oppo has its own Security Manager App where you have to manually allow specific apps to be start up automatically after boot. That's all.

I suspect most android phones has this feature as well thus bear in mind to check whether there is such app and if it does then remind the user to allow the apps in the Security Manager App before they start rebooting their phone and not able to use any service's your App intended to provide.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it worked for me.

```
    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:name=".Broadcast"
                  android:permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: Already got it working and left my solution below. It was due to the phone setting instead of androidmanifest.